# I have 2 classes php with same name and some same functions

Tags: php

I have 2 classes with same name,
I need to use second class extend the first class
and all functions in the second class execute parent function and pass same parameters auto, when call any function.

example:

//classA.php

```
<?php
class first{
    function print_me(){
        echo "me";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
//classB.php
class_alias("first","first_orgin",true);
class first_new extends first_orgin{
    function print_me(){
        parent::print_me();
        echo "me_child";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
?>

include_once "classA.php";

include_once "classB.php";

use first_new as  first;
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: This is not really possible. That fact that you declare an `alias` for the original class does not mean that the original name is not taken any more. That means you have a name collision. You could use name spaces to resolve this, so move the original class into its own name space (and a separate file).